# Troubles with accessing pinia store variable on other file

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, pinia

I have an issue with Pinia in Nuxt3.

I want to set the user_id when I log in and then access it in my middleware. This is purely for redirecting users to the login if they're not logged in.

Issue is: In my console.log the userId is set to null. And I am not sure why and how I can possibly fix it. Any help is appreciated.

redirect middleware (redirect.global.ts)

```js
import { useAuthStore } from '~/store/auth';

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to: any, from: any) => {
    // Access the authentication store
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
    console.log(authStore.userId);

    // Check if 'userId' exist  s in the store
    if (!authStore.userId) {
        // Check if the user is on the "/login" or "/register" routes
        if (to.path !== '/login' && to.path !== '/register') {
            // Redirect the user to the login page
            navigateTo('http://127.0.0.1:3000/login', { external: true });
            return false;
        }
    }

    // User is authenticated or on a permitted route, continue with the route
    return true;
});
```

login.post.ts

```js
import mysql from 'mysql2';
import { useAuthStore } from '~/store/auth';


export default eventHandler(async (event) => {
    let body = await readBody(event);

    try {
        const connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'api_countries',
        });

        const checkUserQuery = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?';
        const checkUserValues = [body.username, body.password];

        const userQueryResult: any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.query(checkUserQuery, checkUserValues, (error, results, fields) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.error('Error checking user:', error);
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve(results);
                }
            });
        });

        if (userQueryResult.length === 0) {
            // User not found, return an error or appropriate response
            return {
                success: false,
                msg: "User not found or password incorrect",
            }
        }

        const user_id = userQueryResult[0].id;
        // After successful login
        const authStore = await useAuthStore();
        authStore.setUserId(user_id); // Assuming you have the 'user_id' value available after the login

        connection.destroy()
        return {
            success: true,
            msg: "Successfully logged in.",
            user_id
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
})
```

pinia store (auth.js)

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useAuthStore = defineStore('auth', {
    state: () => ({
        userId: null,
    }),

    actions: {
        setUserId(userId: any) {
            this.userId = userId;
        },

        clearUserId() {
            this.userId = null;
        },
    },

    getters: {
        getUserId(): any {
            return this.userId;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you awaiting this? `await useAuthStore();`  try this instead `const {setUserId}= useAuthStore();`.
Also another question, is pinia usable from Nitro API routes?